# How to delete specific values from table

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I have the following table structure:

table "sample"

```
objectID | objectValues
       1 | 5,6,7
       2 | 6,7,5,8
       3 | 5
       4 | 7,8,9,5,6
       5 | 10,11
       6 | 5
```

So, I want to delete all ",5" or "5," values from "objectValues" and delete all columns which theirs "objectValues" value is only "5". How can I do this?

Comment: is there any programming language (or development environment) involved?

Comment: What do you mean by "delete all columns which theirs "objectValues" value is only "5" "??? Did you mean you need to delete the row where the value is equal to 5?

Comment: use find_in_set, delete from table where find_in_set(5,value)>0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a tricky method using four queries to make this change.

first query for delete all rows when object value is 5

```
DELETE FROM sample WHERE objectValues = 5;
```

second for update rows when is a value is in all places except first and last

```
UPDATE sample 
SET objectValues = REPLACE(objectValues , ',5,', ',');
```

third when the value 5 is on the first place

```
UPDATE sample 
SET objectValues = LEFT(objectValues, LENGTH(objectValues)-2)
WHERE objectValues LIKE '5,%';
```

and last query when the value 5 is on the last place

```
UPDATE sample 
SET objectValues = RIGHT(objectValues, LENGTH(objectValues)-2)
WHERE objectValues LIKE '%,5';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
delete from table where find_in_set(5,objectValues)>0;
```